# Arrange the array element with minimum number of swaps

Tags: algorithms

Given an array with some elements in which elements can occurs multiple
times, so now how to arrange them in such order that no two same elements are together using minimum number of swaps.( it may not be possible to arrange all of them.)

Comment: Can we assume these are integers for simplicity? Do you have any constraints known?